# JQuery basic questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a dropdown menu using the code from [this site](http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-hamburger-drop-down-menu-with-css-and-jquery/).  It provides some jQuery code. I presume this is added to the HTML file, before the closing body tag.  I've then test in a browser on my computer, but it doesn't work – the hamburger icon isn't clickable

I've created a JS Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2jp93xo5/

This is my HTML file

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/master.css">

</head>

<body>
            <div class="mobile-nav">
                <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
                    <div></div>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="responsive-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="our-services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="our-services.html">FAQs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="our-services.html">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
                $('.responsive-menu').addClass('expand')
                $('.menu-btn').addClass('btn-none')
            })

             $( '.close-btn' ).click(function(){
                $('.responsive-menu').removeClass('expand')
                $('.menu-btn').removeClass('btn-none')
            })
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
                 $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
                 $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
                 })
            })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html file?

Comment: you need to add `jQuery` [Library](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) file before calling your script

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Check the JavaScript console in your browser's debugging tools for errors.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll take a look at adding a JQuery Library file (what ever that is). Thank you

Comment: So do I have to copy and paste all that code (from the link you provided) into my HTML file to get the JavaScript to work? Where does it go?

Comment: No, just add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use functions from an external library, such as jQuery, you need to tell the browser to load those functions.  If all you did was copy and paste the code from the linked article, then "not working" is the expected behavior because that code would have an unfulfilled dependency.

References to external JavaScript libraries are *usually* added to HTML files using script tags.

> The HTML Script Element () is used to embed or reference an executable script within an HTML or XHTML document.

[Script tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) look like:

```
<script src="path/file.js"></script>
```

If you want to use a function referenced in a script tag the script tag needs to appear before you call the function.  It's worth noting that script tags are only one of the mechanisms that can be used to reference external dependencies, although it is the simplest and probably the only one you should worry about for now.

You can run jquery locally or on a server.  A popular choice is to use a CDN-hosted jQuery reference, because (a) it will often already be cached by clients; and (b) it reduces load on your server.  You can reference a local file from your local server.  Or, if you have an internet connection available to your local environment you can just plugin the script tag to reference the CDN-hosted jQuery and include it above the other JavaScript code.  That might look like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

A good way to test out pieces of code like in the article you cited are sites like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that provide an online execution environment and allows code-free options for including certain dependencies and other configuration options.

### Update

I took a look at your fiddle.  The JavaScript was malformed and referenced non-existent elements.  I cleaned it up and moved the reference to jQuery to load onDomReady via the **Framework & Extensions** tab on the top left.  The menu now expands and contracts at: http://jsfiddle.net/2jp93xo5/2/ .  Based on the initial version, I would suggest reviewing JavaScript syntax for basic language constructs.  It will make it a lot easier to understand what's wrong with code when you have a clear picture of what valid code looks like.  Also, to be clear:  **Script tags are HTML elements.  They are not a JavaScript construct.  They are used within an HTML document to reference external JavaScript documents, but are invalid as JavaScript syntax.**

Comment: Brilliant. I've learned a lot just this morning. One final issue could be that the mouse curse doesn't change to a pointer (hand), so there is no visual cue that the hamburger is clickable. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is included with all the browsers I know, and activated by default. It is a client-side language so you juste need a client to test (your browser).

You need to include the jquery library, which come in the form of a .js file. You can download it or simply call the one from a CDN like google :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As for where to put your code, there are several responses. I think the easiest one for testing is to put your script tags just before the  end tag.

Note that to use jquery, your code must be placed after the jquery call. So to sum up, you can write:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // your code
    </script>
</body>
```

You can view javascript errors in the console of your browser (Chrome, Firefox and even IE come with one). Just hit F12 and search for "console", here it should log the errors.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the script linking to the JQuery library, but it still isn't working. The hamburger icon isn't clickable. I've opened the Javascript console in Chrome, but it is blank and I don't know how to get it to check the Javascript.

Comment: Your jsfiddle could not work actually. You mixed up html and js in the "javascript" box. This should only contain javascript (it's just as if it was in a file xxx.js called by the html). Just select jquery in the left menu "Frameworks & Extensions" and remove these half html tags from js code (first 2 lines)

Comment: I know this does not really answer to your original question, but I think you will have to read some stuff concerning the way HTML and JS work. Starting with @smartcaveman's response below actually.

Comment: I've removed the html from the 'javascript' box and selected jquery 1.6.4 from the 'Frameworks & Extensions' - and still the dropdown 'button' isn't clickable.

Comment: sorry that should have said jquery 2.1.3

Comment: Actually jquery 1.xx and 2.xx exist now in parallel (and are a little different). Anyway, I could not agree more with @smartcaveman you have to grasp some basic concepts, or you will never will be able to do anything with JS. There are tons of ressource online to learn so don't be afraid to spend some time reading tutorials